# Ubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia 440 driver can't detect display

Tags: 18.04, display

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer as a dual boot, and am currently trying to set up the environment. I have two displays on DisplayPort attached to the computer and only one of them(DFP-0) shows up, and the other one doesn't catch signal. However, when I boot up the computer, the other display(DFP-3) is the one that shows the GRUB menu.

I want to have both of the displays to work when I am working on Ubuntu.

I have tried to see xrandr, but only DP-0 is detected

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     74.97*+  60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Here is the output from /var/log/Xorg.0.log
As you can see DFP-3 is the one that has the (boot) mark, but is not detected later on.
I would assume it is something with nvidia driver, but have no idea.

```
102 [     3.977] ▸Module class: X.Org Server Extension
103 [     3.977] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  440.26  Sun Oct 13 17:44:48 UTC 2019
104 [     3.978] (II) NVIDIA: The X server does not support PRIME Render Offload.
105 [     4.510] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
106 [     4.510] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
107 [     4.510] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
108 [     4.510] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
109 [     4.510] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3 (boot)
110 [     4.510] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
111 [     4.510] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-5
112 [     4.510] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-6
113 [     4.510] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using ConnectedMonitor string "DFP-0".
114 [     4.511] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce RTX 2060 (TU106-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
115 [     4.511] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 6291456 kBytes
116 [     4.511] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 90.06.2e.40.05
117 [     4.511] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
118 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics MP59G (DFP-0): connected
119 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics MP59G (DFP-0): Internal DisplayPort
120 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics MP59G (DFP-0): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
121 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):    
122 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
123 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
124 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
125 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):    
126 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
127 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
128 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
129 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):    
130 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
131 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
132 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
133 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):    
134 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
135 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
136 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
137 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):    
138 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
139 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
140 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
141 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):    
142 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
143 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
144 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
145 [     4.512] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):    
146 [     4.552] (==) NVIDIA(0):        
147 [     4.552] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
148 [     4.552] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
149 [     4.552] (==) NVIDIA(0):        
150 [     4.553] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
151 [     4.553] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
152 [     4.553] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
153 [     4.592] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (81, 80); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Quick note: It used to work fine when I was using Ubuntu 19.04 with Nvidia driver 418.something before I move to 18.04